# What are a,b, and c in $(3)/(x^3+ax^2+bx+c)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

What are a,b, and c for the function $(3)/(x^3+ax^2+bx+c)$ with asymptotes at x=0, y=0, x=2 and x=4?

I got stuck when I tried to calculate

$2^3+2^2a+2b+c=4^3+4^2a+4b+c$.

$8+4a+2b+c=64+16a+4b+c$.

$56+12a+2b=0$

Comment: simply set denominator to be 0 for x=0,2,4. 3 equation 3 variables

Answer (score 2):

It is enough if you expand the product $(x-0)(x-2)(x-4)=x^3-6x^2+8x$. Then $a=-6$, $b=8$ and $c=0$. The function is $\dfrac{3}{x^3-6x^2+8x}$.

Comment: $\frac{3}{x^3+ax^2+bx^2+c}$ has asymptotes at $ x=0,  x=2$ and $x=4$ implies that $x^3+ax^2+bx^2+c=0$ at $x=0,2,4$. Because a cubic has at most 3 Real (or Complex) roots (see the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra), we know how to factor the cubic. $$x^3+ax^2+bx^2+c=D(x-0)(x-2)(x-3)$$
$D=1$ because $x^3$ has a coefficient of $1$.